# C# Skips first row but want it to skip last row instead

Tags: c#, linq

Not sure if this is the best way but here's my code so far. Currently, it keeps the first duplicate and deletes the others from the table. I want it to keep the last row with the largest `OrderId` number and delete the rest. I've tried `Take` instead of `Skip` but can't seem to get it working properly.

```
var duplicateRow = (from o in db.Orders
                    group o by new { o.CustomerId } into results
                    select results.Skip(1)
                    ).SelectMany(a => a);

db.Orders.DeleteAllOnSubmit(duplicateRow);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't use `OrderBy` the result is arbitrary

> I want it to keep the last row with the largest 'OrderId' number

Then use:

```
var duplicateRows =  db.Orders
    .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => OrderId).Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reverse():

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class O
    {
        public int CustomerId;
        public int OrderId;
        public O(int c,int o) 
        {
            CustomerId = c; 
            OrderId = o;
        }

        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return string.Format("(C_ID: {0}, O_ID:{1})",CustomerId, OrderId);
        }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new O[]{ new O(1,1),new O(2,1),new O(3,1),new O(1,2)};

        var duplicateRow = (from o in data
                            group o by new { o.CustomerId } into results
                            select results.Reverse().Take(1) // reverse and then take 1
                           ).SelectMany(a => a);

        foreach( var o in duplicateRow)
                Console.WriteLine(o);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(C_ID: 1, O_ID:2)
(C_ID: 2, O_ID:1)
(C_ID: 3, O_ID:1)
```

This works due to stableness - if your input have later OrderID earlier you need to OrderBy as well.